# How to replace Linux command with variable in for loop?

Tags: shell-script, for

These are my sample files

```
user@linux:~$ ls -l | cut -d ' ' -f 10-

01. old Name.txt
02. old Name.txt
03. old Name.txt
test.txt
user@linux:~$
```

This is what I want to do.

```
user@linux:~$ for output in *'old Name'*; do echo $output; done
01. old Name.txt
02. old Name.txt
03. old Name.txt
user@linux:~$
```

Since the actual code is using `old Name` multiple times, so I would like to put this on variable.

So, linux command in this case is `*'old Name'*`

Attempt 1 doesn't work, so I tried different way

```
user@linux:~$ cmd='old Name'
user@linux:~$ for output in $cmd; do echo $output; done
old
Name
user@linux:~$
```

Attempt 2

```
cmd="*'old Name'*""
for output in $cmd; do echo $output; done
```

However, it doesn't work

```
user@linux:~$ cmd="*'old Name'*""
> for output in $cmd; do echo $output; done
> 
>
```

Attempt 3

```
cmd='old Name'
for output in ${*'cmd'*}; do echo $output; done
```

Also doesn't work

```
cmd='old Name'
user@linux:~$ for output in ${*'cmd'*}; do echo $output; done
bash: ${*'cmd'*}: bad substitution
user@linux:~$
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: `for output in *"$cmd"*`

Answer (score 1):

You have the loop

```sh
for filename in *'old Name'*; do
    echo "$filename"
done
```

and you want to change the pattern `*'old Name'*` so that the string `old Name` is kept in a variable.

This can be done with

```sh
name='old Name'

for filename in *"$name"*; do
    echo "$filename"
done
```

or just

```sh
printf '%s\n' *"$name"*
```

To have the pattern work correctly, the parts of the pattern that contain filename globbing wildcards must stay unquoted.  The `*` characters can't therefore be part of the `name` variable's value if we quote `$name`.  If they were, they would be used as literal `*` characters, not as wildcards.

At the same time, we don't want to use the `name` variable *unquoted*, as that would break it apart into two words on the space, and you'd end up with two separate patterns.

This is why setting `name` to the string `old Name` and the using `*"$name"*` in the loop, as shown above, would probably be the best solution.